# Regular expression for phone number check does not work

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I'm trying to use a regular expression for checking phone numbers.
Below is the code I'm using:

```
phnum ='1-234-567-8901'
pattern =  re.search('^\+?\d{0,3}\s?\(?\d{3}\)?[-.\s]?d{3}[-.\s]?d{4}$',phnum,re.IGNORECASE)
print(pattern)
```

Even for simple numbers it does not seem to work. Can anyone please correct me where am going wrong?

Comment: You need to escape special characters (`+`, `?`, `-`, `.`,  `(`, `)` etc.), by escape I mean `\+` for example. That should be done when they are used as symbol and not part of the regex. So in your case the first plus should be escaped and possibly some other characters too

Comment: I'd recommend using something like [regex101](https://regex101.com/), but this seems to work for me: `(\d-)?(\d{3})-(\d{3})-(\d{4})`

Comment: @Galunid escaping a regex string is much cleaner using raw strings: `r""`.

Comment: @blorgon Yes, good point

Answer (score 0):

Here's a potential solution. I'm not great at regex, so I may be missing something.

```py
import re

phone_pattern = re.compile(r"^(\+?\d{0,2}-)?(\d{3})-(\d{3})-(\d{4})$")
phone_numbers = ["123-345-6134",
                 "1-234-567-8910",
                 "+01-235-235-2356",
                 "123-123-123-123",
                 "1-asd-512-1232",
                 "a-125-125-1255",
                 "234-6721"]

for num in phone_numbers:
    print(phone_pattern.findall(num))
```

Output:

```
[('', '123', '345', '6134')]
[('1-', '234', '567', '8910')]
[('+01-', '235', '235', '2356')]
[]
[]
[]
[]
```

Answer (score 0):

The immediate problem is that you are missing the `\` before the last two `d`:s. Furthermore, the first `\s` obviously does not match a dash.

I would also strongly encourage `r'...'` raw strings for all regexes, to avoid having Python's string parser from evaluating some backslash sequences before they reach the regex engine.

```py
phnum ='1-234-567-8901'
pattern = re.search(
    r'^\+?\d{0,3}[-.\s]?\(?\d{3}\)?[-.\s]?\d{3}[-.\s]?\d{4}$',
    phnum, re.IGNORECASE)
print(pattern)
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/EYtTKZ

More fundamentally, perhaps you should only accept a closing parenthesis if there is an opening parenthesis before it, etc. A common approach is to normalize number sequences before attempting to use them as phone numbers, but it's a bit of a chicken and egg problem. (You don't want to get false positives on large numbers or IP addresses, for example.)